# What method to send user message?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to send a message to the users. I use a message object but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
        $sAccessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $aParams = array(
            'method'=> 'message',
            'format' => 'post',
            'from'=> $sFrom,
            'to' => $aTo, 
            'message' => $sMessage,
            'access_token' => $sAccessToken,
        );
        $facebook->api($aParams);
```

I got only error with message: Unknown method

Thx for help.

Comment: Do you need to do it server side? You can do it easily using the send dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: I think the problem is that there's no method called 'message' - this is why the error message says 'unknown method' - where in the documentation did you find something that led you to try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Message GraphAPI end point isn't ready yet so that may be why you are having this issue.

> Please note: We are in the process of making the new messages system
>   available to all users, at which point this API will replace the
>   /inbox/ graph API endpoint. We are providing early access to this API
>   for registered developer accounts only until the new messaging system
>   is broadly available. You should use the /inbox endpoint for
>   production applications at the current time.

Source: [Facebook API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to post on a user's wall. If so, from what you have posted there is a mistake. Method should be POST not message. Try the one given below. It should work. Let me know.

```
$sAccessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$aParams =  array(
    'access_token' => $sAccessToken,
    'message' => "Hello, here is a post";
    );
$facebook->api('/OBJECT_ID/feed', 'POST', $aParams);
```

where OBJECT_ID is the Facebook User ID of the user whose wall on which the message need to be posted.

### Alternate method

Anyway executing a link in the format given below will definetly work

https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/feed?method=POST&message=YOUR_MESSAGE&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

where OBJECT_ID is the Facebook User ID of the user whose wall on which the message need to be posted. YOUR_MESSAGE is the message to be published. ACCESS_TOKEN is a valid user access token.

A request in above format will publish a post on OBJECT_ID's wall on behalf of the owner of the access token.

### Reason for error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

This error occurs when no "publish_stream" permission is granted on the access token. How did you verify that you have the permission.

Try this tool to find out whether the permission is granted or not.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and let me know

### HOW TO CREATE POST WITH PAGE AS OWNER?

Facebook GRAPH API allows an application to create a Post with a page as owner instead of a normal Facebook user. For this you need manage_pages and publish_stream extended permissions.

**STEPS**

if you know the Facebook ID of the Fan page go to https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=FAN_PAGE_ID&fields=name,access_token&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

otherwise go to https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts&fields=id,name,access_token&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

after logging in to Facebook.

You will get a list of accounts handled by the logged in user or the required Fan page. In that you can find your fan page details along with an access_token. Use that access token instead of the normal user access token. When you create a post with this new access token entries will be created in the name of the page and not as a normal Facebook user.

Comment: Hi thx for help I tryed send message to my self but only what i got is error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action any ideas?

Comment: For posting messages you should grant publish_stream extended permission. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes I know and I have this permission maby i have some mistake in code: `$aUsersId[] = someId;
        $aUsersId[] = someId2;
        $sAccessToken = $oFacebook->getAccessToken();
        foreach($aUsersId as $iKey => $iUser){
            $aParams =  array(
            'access_token' => $sAccessToken,
            'message' => "Some message",
            );
            $oFacebook->api('/'.$iUser.'/feed/','post',$aParams);
                        
        }`

Comment: yes you are right. I did not have those permissions before. Thanks for your help.  I have another question: how can I send a message from Fan Page?

Comment: You are welcome. I haven't worked with Fan page yet. Can you give me a sample url or code related to this Fan page. I may be able to help you.

Comment: here you are [https://www.facebook.com/pages/Language-School/158500650832284?ref=ts] and app [https://apps.facebook.com/quiz_dla_gimnazjum/] (but this is in polish) What I need is to send a massage to users who use the app when the new quiz is available, but the message sender should be a Fan Page not me.